# Error while trying to convert string into a dictionary (python)

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm trying to convert the following into a dictionary

```
my_string='{"values": [["searchText", "aaaa bbbb"], ["url", "https://aaa.com/w/Try.do?one=yes&amp;isFate=true&amp;active=2&amp;entry=aaaa+bbbb"], ["ip", "11.22.333.44, 12.12.3.111"], ["userId", "4569874"], ["id", 69875462145], ["sessionId", "25F8D032D8FGJ5ED023F56ZZ.TRYING207"], ["pageNumber", null], ["dateCreated", "2018-03-06 17:23:55"], ["page_id", 771790], ["dateModified", "2018-03-06 17:23:55"], ["device_id", 168]]}'
```

But when I do this:

```
ast.literal_eval(my_string)
```

It raises the following error:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x000001F2C0536080>
```

Can you help me with this please ?

Thank you in advance

PS: I'm using python 3.6

Comment: In the future, if you want to save a python dictionary, you should use json.dumps to store the dictionary, and then json.loads to load it. You can also use pickling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to load your data is to use `json.loads` function as was mentioned in comment to your question.

But if you strongly want to use `ast.literal_eval` function, the reason of `ValueError` is this part of `my_string`:

> `... ["pageNumber", null] ...`

There is no `null` constant, class or type in Python. Change it to `None`.